# Python - Group columns with same first five characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas data frame with many columns. Each cell has a number in it. Each column's name is a location code, and I am trying to consolidate them by summing the rows of the ones that have the same first 5 characters, but cannot seem to find a way to do this. In other words, if columns have the same first 5 characters, they get grouped together. Any help?

Comment: Please always post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, suppose you have this MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ABC1': [1,2,3], 
                   'XYZ1': [10,20,30], 
                   'ABC2': [1,2,3], 
                   'XYZ9': [100,200,300]})

    ABC1    XYZ1    ABC2    XYZ9
0   1       10      1       100
1   2       20      2       200
2   3       30      3       300
```

And you want to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the first three characters of your columns.

Then, you can group against `axis=1` as below

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[:3],axis=1).sum()


    ABC XYZ
0   2   110
1   4   220
2   6   330
```

Comment: Thank you that was perfect!